# How is nil instantiated from the NilClass

Tags: ruby

As we know, (almost) everything in Ruby is an object which is an instance of a class.
`nil` is an object too:

```
2.1.3 :016 > nil.object_id
 => 8
```

And it is an instance of the `NilClass`:

```
2.1.3 :017 > nil.class
 => NilClass
```

And an object is instantiated using the `new` method.

Inspecting the `NilClass`, I found out it doesn't have a `new` method:

```
2.1.3 :021 > NilClass.methods.sort
 => [:!, :!=, :!~, :<, :<=, :<=>, :==, :===, :=~, :>, :>=, :__id__, :__send__, :allocate, :ancestors, :autoload, :autoload?, :class, :class_eval, :class_exec, :class_variable_defined?, :class_variable_get, :class_variable_set, :class_variables, :clone, :const_defined?, :const_get, :const_missing, :const_set, :constants, :define_singleton_method, :display, :dup, :enum_for, :eql?, :equal?, :extend, :freeze, :frozen?, :hash, :include, :include?, :included_modules, :inspect, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :instance_method, :instance_methods, :instance_of?, :instance_variable_defined?, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variables, :is_a?, :kind_of?, :method, :method_defined?, :methods, :module_eval, :module_exec, :name, :nil?, :object_id, :prepend, :private_class_method, :private_constant, :private_instance_methods, :private_method_defined?, :private_methods, :protected_instance_methods, :protected_method_defined?, :protected_methods, :public_class_method, :public_constant, :public_instance_method, :public_instance_methods, :public_method, :public_method_defined?, :public_methods, :public_send, :remove_class_variable, :remove_instance_variable, :respond_to?, :send, :singleton_class, :singleton_class?, :singleton_method, :singleton_methods, :superclass, :taint, :tainted?, :tap, :to_enum, :to_s, :trust, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?]
```

Now, just out of curiousity, how is the `nil` object instantiated from the `NilClass` when there is no `new` method?

Comment: 1. There don't have to be `new` method. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html uses `Klass#instance`. 2. I think `nil` is hardcoded in a C/C++ (I don't remember which one **Standard Ruby** uses). https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0ef94bd2afa035648032e382201f1c9af29c5c3a/object.c#L3360 read till 3377 line. This explain why there is no `new`(and `alloc`). I guess somewhere `rb_cNillClass` is instantiated. You can look for it on github if you want know more (I am bad at searching using github search engine so I guess I missed something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not:

**NilClass**

The class of the singleton object nil.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/NilClass.html

This will make it clearer :

```
irb(main):005:0> a = nil
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> b = nil
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> a.object_id
=> 8
irb(main):008:0> b.object_id
=> 8
```

Comment: The same applies to FalseClass and TrueClass

Comment: @brahmana & papirtiger This code proves that `nil` is an object of some class. `a = nil` and `b = nil` assign the same object, hence object ids are the same. Check this: `o = Object.new; a1 = o; a2 = o; a2.object_id == a1.object_id # true`

Comment: Yes indeed. `nil` is a keyword which points to the singleton object of the class NilClass. That is why every time you refer to the `nil` keyword it always points to the same object which is created by the Ruby VM when it gets initialised. That is why its object_id is `8` (Try it on your system). The same is the case with `true` or `false` keywords. `true.object_id # => 20` and `false.object_id # => 0`

Comment: @brahmana false => 0, true => 2, nil => 4; Fixnums =>  n%2==0. Well, that's on 32bit system. On 64 bit OS it will be different (as you saw it - nil = 8). ps. I think your comment ("is created by the Ruby VM when it gets initialised") answers the question better than papirtiger's or daremkd's answers. I like to think it as `nil` being instantiated only once by some hardcoded c/c++ function.

Comment: Aah yes.. I missed the different architectures. Thanks for pointing that out. Well we all seem to be saying the same thing in different ways and may be with differing levels of detail. :)

Answer (score 1):

Some objects in Ruby are not instantiated including; numbers, symbols, nil, true and false. Take @papirtiger´s code and replace nil with any number, or any symbol, and you'll see the same results.

Comment: I would say `Fixnum`s instead of numbers. `Bignum`s are instantiated.